# Как узнать какие именно стили пересчитались в Firefox Developer Edition?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, html5, firefox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как узнать какое именно применение стилей занимает столько времени и идет просадка fps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `Firefox` в **Профайлер** есть виды отображений

- Водопад
- Дерево вызовов

Как раз в **Дерево вызовов** можно найти вкладку стили и т.п. и посмотреть детально всю информацию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]